# Exoplayer scaling

Tags: android, exoplayer

On exoplayer, I want to force scaling for media source in 720*576.
For the moment, these video is displayed in 4:3, and I want to force display in 16:9.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: you mean ratio of the video?

Comment: Yes I mean ! But I'm think i'm on the way.
Adding :
simpleExoPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL);
and 
player.setVideoScalingMode(C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING);

Comment: Posting existing code helps a lot, and if you discover the fix for this, post it as an answer :)

Comment: That was a general question, not a specific question on a particular code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self answer, the correct response was :

```
simpleExoPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL);
```

And

```
player.setVideoScalingMode(C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING);
```

Now display is fine, even if my source is in 4:3 ratio.